How to Change RecyclerView Item Layout When Scrolled to Center Horizontally in Android?
I'm working on an Android app and I want to implement a RecyclerView where the item layout changes when it is scrolled to the center horizontally. I've included an image below to show what I'm aiming for:

What I Want to Achieve:
When an item in the RecyclerView is scrolled to the center, I want it to change its layout to make it look more prominent (e.g., larger size, different background, etc.).
What I've Tried:

I have implemented a basic RecyclerView with a horizontal LinearLayoutManager.
I have searched for tutorials, but I could only find examples of standard RecyclerView
implementations.

My Code So Far:
Here is the basic setup of my RecyclerView:
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(myData);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

My adapter:
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<MyData> mData;

public MyAdapter(List<MyData> data) {
    this.mData = data;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Bind data to the item
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
  }
}

How can I detect when an item is centered and change its layout accordingly? Are there specific methods or listeners in RecyclerView that I can use to achieve this effect?
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Have a look at this gist. It changes the layout manager to scale the child at the mid point. It may be what you're after. https://gist.github.com/Spikeysanju/91e566f9078325ecf1b57e66c98b7847

For this, you need to use a viewpager and not a recyclerview. A viewpager is what shown in the image you attached.
Have a look at ViewPager2 and this blog.
Once, you setup viewpager, you can use any existing page transformer or write you own for your custom needs.

@Tuấn Nguyễn as you are a new contributor to SO, I want to let you know that you can accept the answer if it helped or worked for your problem.

Thank you, it help me very much with this ui
